# Can't "git bisect reset" ; endless stash/reset loop

Tags: git

After bisecting I'd like to return back to the normal state and restore the most recent version.

However, git *git bisect reset* complains that certain files with local changes would be overridden by checkout and that I should *stash* first.

Stashing and trying again to reset complains that some different file would be overwritten and I should stash.  Stashing that one brings me back to the first error, and so on and so on in a loop.

i.e.

**git stash ; git bisect reset**

Error: Files A, B, and C would be over written. Please stash

**git stash ; git bisect reset**

Error: File D would be over written. Please stash

**git stash ; git bisect reset**

Error: Files A, B, and C would be over written. Please stash

**git stash ; git bisect reset**

Error: File D would be over written. Please stash

and so on.  I'd like to clear all the bisecting and return to the latest commit.

Any ideas?

*[Full transcript]*

```
   powerpro:source_build danny$ git stash ; git bisect reset
Saved working directory and index state WIP on (no branch): 01993b2 tsAnalysis changed to little Endian (htonl() etc)
HEAD is now at 01993b2 tsAnalysis changed to little Endian (htonl() etc)
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    src/ep/dtapiTsp/dtapibridge/include/DtCommon.h
    src/ep/dtapiTsp/dtapibridge/include/DtPortAsi.h
    src/ep/dtapiTsp/dtapibridge/src/DtPortAsi.cpp
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
Could not check out original HEAD '37c9eb1f56b0669b8382c1c3af68cfb73f6758b3'.
Try 'git bisect reset <commit>'.
powerpro:source_build danny$ git stash ; git bisect reset
Saved working directory and index state WIP on (no branch): 01993b2 tsAnalysis changed to little Endian (htonl() etc)
HEAD is now at 01993b2 tsAnalysis changed to little Endian (htonl() etc)
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    src/ep/dtapiTsp/DtapiBridge/src/DtPortAsi.cpp
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
Could not check out original HEAD '37c9eb1f56b0669b8382c1c3af68cfb73f6758b3'.
Try 'git bisect reset <commit>'.
powerpro:source_build danny$ git stash ; git bisect reset
Saved working directory and index state WIP on (no branch): 01993b2 tsAnalysis changed to little Endian (htonl() etc)
HEAD is now at 01993b2 tsAnalysis changed to little Endian (htonl() etc)
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    src/ep/dtapiTsp/dtapibridge/include/DtCommon.h
    src/ep/dtapiTsp/dtapibridge/include/DtPortAsi.h
    src/ep/dtapiTsp/dtapibridge/src/DtPortAsi.cpp
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
Could not check out original HEAD '37c9eb1f56b0669b8382c1c3af68cfb73f6758b3'.
Try 'git bisect reset <commit>'.
powerpro:source_build danny$ git stash ; git bisect reset
Saved working directory and index state WIP on (no branch): 01993b2 tsAnalysis changed to little Endian (htonl() etc)
HEAD is now at 01993b2 tsAnalysis changed to little Endian (htonl() etc)
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    src/ep/dtapiTsp/DtapiBridge/src/DtPortAsi.cpp
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
Could not check out original HEAD '37c9eb1f56b0669b8382c1c3af68cfb73f6758b3'.
Try 'git bisect reset <commit>'.
```

Comment: The symptoms match up with files that are untracked: `git stash` won't save and remove them by default, and `git checkout` (which `git bisect reset` needs to do) won't overwrite them unless they're marked as "trashable" by being listed in a `.gitignore` or equivalent.  `git status` will tell you if there are such untracked files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is you have incompatible changes from the previous `HEAD` (when you started the bisect) and the current state of the bisect `HEAD` (probably some untracked files).

You could just reset everything and start over

```
git bisect reset HEAD    
git checkout your_branch --force
git reset HEAD --hard
```

Then, you should check for any untracked files with `git status` and resolve them if there are any. I bet you'll find a file that exists now, but was deleted in a previous commit.

Comment: Would that lose any data or history?

Comment: You will lose changes that were made between the last `git commit` and when you ran `git bisect start`. You will also lose changes after `git bisect start`, but you would lose those anyway. Also, it doesn't have to be `master`, it could be whatever branch you want.